# rsync: how to copy a file that might not exist without an error

Tags: rsync, make

I have a command in my Makefile that sync's up my bibliographies from an external source. If `rsync` fails because the target file does not exist `rsync` exits with error 23. I can *hide* the error by piping the output to `/dev/null` but this still causes my Makefile to exit. How can I get the following Makefile code to output `"Hi"` when `$(bib_dir)` does not exist?

```
sync_bibliography:
    rsync $(bib_dir) bib 2>/dev/null
    echo "HI"
```

Comment: You can use the OR operator `||`: `false || echo "Hi"` outputs *Hi*

Comment: @Marco That's perfect! I didn't know about the `||` operator (but I did know about `&&`, so I guess it was the next step...). Put it in an answer an I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the OR operator `||`. If the previous command fails and return false, the command on the right side is executed. Example:

```
false || echo "The previous command failed"
```

or in your case

```
rsync $(bib_dir) bib 2>/dev/null || echo "HI"
```

Comment: With your suggestion I went one better and gave myself some feedback: `rsync $(bib_bib) bib 2>/dev/null && echo "Bibliography sync complete" || echo "Bibliography sync failed" && true`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Put the rsync command inside of a shell script and then call the shell script inside of the Makefile.  At the end of the shell script, use something that will always return true such as `sleep 0`.

Comment: Excuse my shell-ignorance, but doesn't that put me in the same situation? The shell script still fails when rsync fails, does the error not get passed to the script itself? Can you put a MWE that shows how to exit a shell script with no error even if a line fails?